# Liferay Portlet-Servlet communication

Tags: spring, servlets, liferay, communication, portlet

I have a Spring 3 MVC servlet webservice based application which I now intend to integrate with my liferay based system. In liferay we use IPC (Inter portlet communication) to communicate between portlets.

An event is broadcasted by a portlet which is then processed by other portlets and corresponding actions are taken. This communication is currently being carried out using IPC.

I have now deployed my servlet application in Liferay in an iframe. Will it be possible for me to establish similar processing of the broadcasted event? Any solutions for portlet-servlet communication?

Thank you.

Comment: AFAIK , IPC is between Portlets..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IPC` stands for `Inter Portlet Communication`, so, there has to be portlets and cannot be done between a `servlet` and a `portlet`. If you really wants to share data between a servlet and portlet, you can use the `HttpSession` to store the object and share. Also, you can call the Servlet by using `PortalDelegateServlet` from Liferay.

Also, when you use `Iframe`, you actually do not communicate between the iframe window and the window opener application.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank You. I assumed that such an approach can be achieved by extending the bridge implementation which is provided by Liferay.